# Modifying windows hosts file

Tags: c#, windows, text-files

I am looking to edit the hosts file at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

So every time I start the program it checks if the text that I want to add (`123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com`) and if it isn't written in the hosts file it adds it and continues running the code and if it is it skips and doesn't add `123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com` and continues running the code.

So I am looking to do that

This is the code:

```
var hostfile = "";
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
var OSInfo = Environment.OSVersion;
if (OSInfo.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
{
    //is windows NT
    HOSTFILE = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), @"system32\drivers\etc\hosts");
}
else
{
    //is no windows NT
    HOSTFILE = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "hosts");
}
Console.WriteLine(HOSTFILE);
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
var myIP = host.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();
File.AppendAllLines(HOSTFILE, new[] {string.Format("123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com", myIP) });    
Console.ReadLine();
InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: So any questions? What is the problem with your current code????

Comment: so what is the problem with your code? what is supposed to be different?

Comment: I want to make it so it checks if  123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com is there and if it isn't it adds it to the hosts file. Currently the problem is it keeps adding a new line every time I run it.[11:24:56 AM] []Yuki[] MythicalTR: its add a new line every time we run the program. I just want to be 1 time.

Comment: so simply `File.AppendLine("123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com");` ?

Comment: Why do you even use `String.Format`?

Comment: Ye but it only does it once. if I run it again it doesn't add it because it checks if it is already added.

Comment: you should use file stream to read the files lines

Comment: @gilmishal That's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
File.AppendAllLines(hostfile, new[] { string.Format("123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com", myIP) });
```

More particularly this part of it which just does nothing because a placehoder in the `string.Format` is missing:

```
 new[] { string.Format("123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com", myIP) }
```

If you really just want to add `123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com` to the file if it's not present I would do it like this:

```
const string tales = "123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com";
if (!File.ReadAllLines(hostfile).Contains(tales))
{
     File.AppendAllLines(hostfile, new String[] { tales });
}
```

**Entire code:**

```
var OSInfo = Environment.OSVersion;
string pathpart = "hosts";
if (OSInfo.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
{
    //is windows NT
    pathpart = "system32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts";
}
string hostfile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), pathpart);

const string tales = "123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com";
if (!File.ReadAllLines(hostfile).Contains(tales))
{
    File.AppendAllLines(hostfile, new String[] { tales });
}
```

Do not forget to ensure your program runs with administrator privileges otherwise you will get an `unauthorized access exception` by `.net`.

**2nd edit** on order to change it to `123.123.123.123` if `download.talesrunner.com` already is in the file with a different ip:

```
    const string tales = "123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(hostfile);

    if (lines.Any(s => s.Contains("download.talesrunner.com")))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
             if (lines[i].Contains("download.talesrunner.com"))
                 lines[i] = tales;
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(hostfile, lines);
    }
    else if (!lines.Contains(tales))
    {
        File.AppendAllLines(hostfile, new String[] { tales });
    }
```

Comment: I am receiving this error message : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: the @ should be outside the string.

Comment: either outside or just remove it and make double splashes inside the path. I just edited my post therefor.

Comment: have you copied the entire code I posted? I just tried it without any error.

Comment: please try replacing your program with this or making a new ConsoleProject: http://pastebin.com/Yz1ahPd0

Comment: if it is still not working then paste your code with the exact error message you get.

Comment: it worked fine . Sorry for asking too much but is it possible also to do this : some ppl have another ip in their host file other than 123.123.123.123
it should be replaced by 123.123.123.123

Comment: why did you not accept my answer then if it worked? you only can accept one answer.

Comment: It worked just need an edit on the code you gave me .

Comment: ok thank you just 1 question where do I edit ? maybe you can update the paste bin so its the full code. Please and thank you . I will accept soon. ( I tried adding it and there is this error message : a local variable names 'tales' is already defined )

Comment: 1 problem if there is another ip it does nothing to it

Comment: same thing as before.

Comment: please try this: http://pastebin.com/Y7bXryi6  if it is still not working please provide your hosts.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append your entry only if it doesn't exist WITHOUT reading the hosts file then you need to change your Dns queries

```
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("download.talesrunner.com");
if (host != null)
{
    bool hasEntry = false;
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.ToString() == "123.123.123.123")
        {
            hasEntry = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!hasEntry)
        File.AppendAllLines(..., 
}
```

Then your code that writes the entry doesn't seem to be correct. An entry in the hosts file is composed of an IP address followed by a series of host names separated by a space or tab so, if you want to redirect every call to "download.talesrunner.com" to the IP address "123.123.123.123" and your IP address then you need to add

```
string[] entry = new string[] 
         { "123.123.123.123 download.talesrunner.com " + MyIp };
File.AppendAllLines(HOSTFILE, entry);
```

Comment: I am receiving this error message same as Kai's : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Illegal characters in path

Comment: Uhm, not sure where this invalid char is. Did you get the exception on the AppendLines line? Did you add a space after _"... download.talesrunner.com "_ ?